# Avoiding a particular host in condor

Tags: condor

There's one host on my condor grid which is bad for some reason, i.e. jobs run on this host run forever. I'm not the administrator and can't log into, hence I can't investigate and nor take it out of the grid. I'd like to simply specify in my submit file that I don't want to run jobs on that one host. What's the syntax for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set your requirements to exclude the host. Something like this might work:

```
Requirements = (Machine != "bad.hostname.org")
```

Comment: I know this is quite an old question, but how would you exclude a specific IP? When I write `Machine != "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"` it does still seem to execute no that host...

Comment: Maybe something like this might help:
`Rank = (machine != ip_address)`. Or try to find the hostname using either `nslookup ip_address` or `dig ip_address`.